# Enforce intent content while starting an activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 `activities` - A & B. Activity B is started via activity A, but it needs a piece of information (a `String`) to startup. Right now I am using `putExtra` & `getExtras` methods of `Intent` class to pass the data around. In any way can I enforce the requirement that the intent that is used to start activity B should always have a `String` stored using a particular key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't enforce it, but:

- You can create a `static` method on activity B that is responsible for starting instances of activity B, and have that method take your `String` parameter. That method would be responsible for building the `Intent`, putting in the extras, and calling `startActivity()`. So long as the rest of your code uses this method, you will always have your extra.
- You can always validate that the extra exists in `onCreate()`/`onNewIntent()`.

But there's no way you can teach Android to automatically reject an `Intent` that is missing some extra.

Comment: I cannot make the constructor of an activity private as it would cause the android framework to throw an error if I try to start it!! Therefore using the "static method" pattern would still leave a way of starting the activity without the required extras!! So I decided to go with validating the extras in `onCreate` and throw an error if it doesn't have the expected keys. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @x-treme: "I cannot make the constructor of an activity private as it would cause the android framework to throw an error if I try to start it" -- that's why I didn't suggest that. "Therefore using the "static method" pattern would still leave a way of starting the activity without the required extras" -- correct. However, it makes it easier to comply with the requirement.